# iOS App with InAppPurchase & 2 Targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I've created an App with IAP (only one non-consumable) and made a Trial and a Full Target. All works fine (I think) until now.
If I launch the trial or full version with the simulator all work, even the IAP method. But the problem is : how can change the target when the user buy the full version? 
in Xcode I can select & launch the version (target) I want, but how do I establish that the starting target is the trial version and not the full?
I've add a Swift Flag in Xcode but maybe I misunderstood its operation.
do I have to start over?

Comment: You only want one target and one app in the store. Why do you have two targets and two apps?

Comment: "how can change the target when the user buy the full version?"  You live in a virtual world with the iPhone simulator.  Actual users don't.  Besides, if you spell the word 'trial,' they can reject your app.

Comment: I don't think you understand how IAP works in this case; You only have one version.  The "full" features are disabled in code until the purchase is made.

Comment: <maddy> I have ONE app with TWO target..

Comment: I've add the targets method following this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

```
func startBuyingProducts() {
    let purchaseRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(arrayLiteral:productID))
    purchaseRequest.delegate = self
    purchaseRequest.start()
}

// SKPridcutsRequestDelegate method
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if let product = response.products.first {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        }
    }    


//implement method of SKPaymentTransactionObserver 
//trigger the unlock feature method when the purchase succeed and the receipt return is verified through apple
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                if let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL {
                    let request = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: receiptURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                        let receiptJSON = data?.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

                        //verify the receipt throught apple, or sending the verification throught your own server
                        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!)
                        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                        request.httpMethod = "POST"
                        request.httpBody = receiptJSON?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                            // unlock the feature here
                        })
                    })
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                break
            case .purchasing:
                break
            case .restored: break
        }
    }
}
```

Only one target needed.